# Strategies for approaching a client requirement to create quizzes

Tags: 7, webforms

One of my clients requirements seems to stretch Drupal's boundaries, and is forcing me to think differently on how to approach a problem. I am looking at potential alternatives and strategies to the following requirement so that I can get it right:

My client essentially wants to be able to create quizzes. We are unable to use the popular quiz module since it does not have a Drupal 7 version out yet and in any case, does not allow for multiple questions to be inputted in one go. Explored other module alternatives such as Closed question but they aren't exactly user-friendly.

Getting my hands dirty, my strategy around this is built as follows:

Create a new content type and have it powered via Web-form. The editors can now create questions using the web-forms following an instruction manual about the specific form elements to use. The question set essentially includes : - markup for questions
Radio buttons for option fields with the selected one denoting the correct field
Feedback field The entire question set is put into a fieldset. Subsequent question sets are created by cloning the first fieldset and once done composing, what we have is a node with webform elements that have been structured to appear as a quiz.
The problem:

The editors must follow an instruction manual in order to compose these question-sets and essentially the quiz since they are leveraging the webform. This is also in many ways a pseudo quiz, in the sense, I am leveraging web-forms to simulate what a quiz would appear like and not in essence a quiz. The process is tedious because for each question-set composed, the editors need to click each of these elements and have to fill in data making the process time consuming.

My ideal solution would be to have a content type that would allow the editors to specify a total number of questions in a content type and then have it generate the question-set(question markup, answer options as radio buttons, feedback). This would allow editors to quickly bang in the required content and in the process quickly compose quizzes.

Essentially the question is, if anybody knows how to achieve the ideal solution and if it is actually possible. If not, looking at the problem I have described, what alternatives are possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that the latest version of the quiz module has a full flow of functionality with Drupal 7 also. I have used the quiz module to develop a site in Drupal 7 and it worked fine. If you have any issue in working with the Quiz module, i am ready to help you out in solving your issue.